# Make current OAuth User Identity retrievable via IoC in WebAPI project

Tags: oauth, dependency-injection, ninject, owin, identity

I have an Owin based OAuth 2.0 implemention in ASP.NET WebAPI 2 application. Given that I set a correct claims to a validated identity, In my controller code I an get the currently authenticated user via this.User property.

I need to setup Ninject kernel that way so on each request the PerRequestScope object is instanciated that would hold a current user, but it would be available in an injectable manner, and not just from controller's code.

Please assist on how this can be done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it.

```
kernel.Bind<IPrincipal>()
  .ToMethod(context => HttpContext.Current.User)
  .InRequestScope();
```

Will allow anyone injecting IPrincipal to get the current user name.

Comment: This does not work. For Web API you need to use HttpRequestContext.Principal. But that is not as static property and you can't access it anywhere except in the actions.